# Docker-Compose freezing on database-creation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wish to expand a web-application using docker (I'm beginner in Docker). My application demands PostgreSQL. Therefore I decided to use the docker-compose.

The `docker-compose.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services: 
    db:
        image: postgres
        command: "postgres -c listen_addresses='*'"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=CatsQMS
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345qwerty

    application:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - db
```

Also I have the file `config.yaml` which configures my web-application, it looks like this:

```yaml
database_config:
  host: db
  user: postgres
  password: 12345qwerty
  port: 5432
  database: CatsQMS

# Unimportant stuff
```

And when I lunch the docker-compose, using `docker-compose up` the build is freezing at this point:

```
Recreating cats_queue_management_system_db_1 ... done
Recreating cats_queue_management_system_application_1 ... done
Attaching to cats_queue_management_system_db_1, cats_queue_management_system_application_1
db_1           |
db_1           | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1           |
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.628 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.628 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.628 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.635 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.660 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-20 13:39:45 UTC
db_1           | 2020-05-20 13:42:51.673 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Perhaps it's an important thing, my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

COPY ./application/sources/database/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python3 setup.py develop

ENTRYPOINT ["start_app", "-d"]
```

Where have I admitted a mistake?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @David Maze something like "Running on http:\\0.0.0.0:8080". But I solved.

Comment: @JuiceFV How did you solve this? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application and PostgreSQL database are running and should work as expected. But Docker attached after running the containers to the `db` container.

You can avoid this by using the option [`-d` or `--detach` on `docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/):

> The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container (essentially running `docker-compose logs -f`). When the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

So your command looks like this:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with the database container. It looks like it starts up normally and is listening for connections.

What is the ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile executing, "start_app"?

The -d argument looks like it may be starting the website as a daemon (background process) which doesn't give docker a process to hook into.

Maybe try
ENTRYPOINT ["start_app"]

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that your web app cant talk to the database? If so it might be that a) they don't share a network, and b) you're trying to connect on port 5432, but the postgres db container is not exposing or publishing this port.

I've added a few things to your docker-compose file that might make it work...

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
    test:

services: 
    db:
        image: postgres
        command: "postgres -c listen_addresses='*'"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=CatsQMS
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345qwerty
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - test

    application:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
            - test
        depends_on:
            - db
```